# How to avoid pixel distortion in HTML elements in varying display settings?

Tags: html, css, screen, screen-density

In certain situations html elements that use pixels are not always rendered as imagined, a simple example is when a person adjusts the browser zoom to about "100%", so depending on the position and zoom one element of height equal to the other seems to be a smaller pixel.

One example is the StackOverflow site menu itself, example with "175%" zoom:

> [image: video affects pixels as you zoom, an example with 175% browser zoom]

Note that the third menu bar appears larger than the others and that the spacing of the first and second bars also appears larger.

This is not just about "zoom", I tested it on a colleague's notebook with Windows10 and `GeForce® GTX 1050` card (of course I understand that in part modern computers render with the *"integrated card"*) and it uses in the **Windows display settings** for the operating system all the value of 125%:

[image: windows 10 set to use font size at 125%]

Using this, I realized that the same problem occurs (even with 100% zoom in the browser).

The only displays that I noticed that the problem does not occur are those of retina displays (and similar "technologies"), because they use a higher "pixel density".

But the question is **NOT** about monitors, displays and market technologies, the question is how to avoid the problem on normal screens when the user adjusts something (like example in Windows10 with 125% on display settings), noting that it varies with resolution and even the monitor and is "unpredictable".

I tried to work with other *units of measure* (`em`, `pt`, `rem`, `%`), but the problem persisted.

So here goes my question:

- How to prevent pixel rendering on elements from being distorted in display settings that may vary?

An example that the problem occurs (chance adjust the source of the "OS" or the zoom):

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #007bff;
}

.v-navbar-toggle {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    background: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 8px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
}

.v-icon-bar {
    background-color: currentColor;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

.v-icon-bar+.v-icon-bar {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<button class="v-navbar-toggle">
    <i class="v-icon-bar"></i>
    <i class="v-icon-bar"></i>
    <i class="v-icon-bar"></i>
</button>
```

> **Note:** I also noticed that working with [svg](/questions/tagged/svg) (depends on how you use it) or [icon-fonts](/questions/tagged/icon-fonts) works a lot better compared [html](/questions/tagged/html)+[css](/questions/tagged/css), but what I am trying to solve are problems with simple "html elements".

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try changing all the pixels to em or percentage value so as to make them all relative.

Comment: @AdityaPrakash Thanks by sugestion, but not work. I create this example https://codepen.io/brcontainer/pen/PooEyrR, and config my Windows display with 125%, and get this results: i.stack.imgur.com/XTbAS.png

Comment: This is related to display scaling of browser engine and OS. I am not sure if we can do anything about it.

Comment: There is a possible solution, as documented in an answer of an similar/duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70020126/2544163