# Why do elements with the same height "look" differently when zoom changes?

Tags: html, css, height, zooming

Basically the gist is in the subject.

When I create two identical divs with fixed height (2px), and change the zoom to 75% or 125%, they "look" differently for some reason, can someone please explain what is going on here? And how do I fix this?

```css
.gradient-slider-line {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue);
    height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="gradient-slider-line"></div>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
<div class="gradient-slider-line"></div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: May be a browser issue, it seems to be working fine on my chrome

Comment: Because sub-pixel rounding is done cumulatively, so the rounding at one position on the page may be one pixel different from the rounding at a different position on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, some research helped but not a complete solution. As the last comment mentioned, it's a subpixel rendering issue, and it's influenced by your Anti Aliasing settings and windows display scaling setting.
I switched to a 0.15 rem instead of 2px, which produced a similar line but the increments at which the line height jumps when zooming in/out are smaller and visually it's much less noticeable.

Comment: Using rem fixed

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed caused by browsers rounding of subpixel values and can be observed in current Chrome and Firefox.
To fix this you should style the border and *not* the height - see:

```css
.line {
  /* 12px leaves _no_ fractions for many zoom factors: */
  margin-top: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.group-height .line {
  /* 1px leaves fractions for many zoom factors: */
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}

.group-border .line {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.group-height {
  border-right: 10px solid green;
}
```

```html
Check visual line apprearances with different browser/OS zoom!<br> Observe that styling with `height` (left side) leads to unexpected rounding effects, whereas `border` (right side) behaves as expected.
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="group-height">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="group-border">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With 125% OS zoom this yields the following result:
[image: result image]